# How to discriminate between 2 different types of users trying to log in?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm writing a Java servlet for a super market web app and I can't discriminate between 2 different types of users logging in.

Customers can log in once they register but I can't seem to figure out how to log in as a provider/supplier (which the admin creates), using the same login page.

Once a provider adds his email and password in the "login.jsp" page, the code should redirect them to the "supplier.jsp" page, but instead it is redirecting them to the loginServlet class

*I'm using the same servlet to login the 2 different types of users and I'm using Tomcat 8.

*From the second if (superMarket == null) it is where I'm having problems.

```
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if (email.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
        response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
    }

    SuperMarket superMarket = (SuperMarket) sesion.getAttribute("SUPER_MARKET");

    if (superMarket == null) {
        //exception
    } else {
        boolean exists = false;
        for (Client client : superMarket.getClientsList()) {

            if (client.getEmail().equals(email) && client.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (exists) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        } else {
            //exception
        }
    }

    if (superMarket == null){
        //exception
    }else {
        boolean existsProvider = false;
        for (Provider provider: superMarket.getProvidersList()){

            if (provider.getEmail().equals(email) && provider.getPassword().equals(password)){
                existsProvider = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (existsProvider) {
            response.sendRedirect("supplier.jsp");
        } else {
            //exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use your debugger. Step through the code line by line. Inspect the values of the variables. Find where your mistake is.

Comment: There is no code in that block, so that can't throw an Exception

Comment: Is it possible that supplier.jsp is protected and forces a second login?